# Pytest Testrail Module - Post Test Results for Test Runs

Tags: python, pytest, testrail

I am trying to use the pytest testrail module and started with this demo script:

```
import pytest
from pytest_testrail.plugin import testrail

@testrail('C165')
def test_run():
    print "T165:pass"
```

It does create a test run but does not post any results to the corresponding test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an assertion as that is what the pytest hook is looking for:

```
import pytest
from pytest_testrail.plugin import testrail

@testrail('C165')
def test_run():
    assert False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `add_result` function. The `testrail` plugin executes it when your test (test_run) is finished.

You can notice the parameter `status` in the function, it requires your test need to return the result from assertion (ex. assert False is good example).

In your case, just print a string is not good to `testrail` know the status of the test.

```
def add_result(self, test_ids, status, comment='', duration=0):
    """
    Add a new result to results dict to be submitted at the end.

    :param list test_ids: list of test_ids.
    :param int status: status code of test (pass or fail).
    :param comment: None or a failure representation.
    :param duration: Time it took to run just the test.
    """
```